# Bilinearity or not of a tensor product

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors, bilinear-form

If I have a tensor field $g$ of type $(0,2)$, in local coordinates expressed as $g=g_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j$, changing coordinates ($x^i\rightarrow y^j$) I obtain the following:
$$ g=g_{ij}(\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^k}dy^k)\otimes(\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^h}dy^h)$$
$\textbf{My questions:}$ Sorry in advance if they are stupid questions but I am new in studying differential geometry...

1. can I consider that the tensor product above is $\textbf{bilinear}$ and so can I write the following?
   $$g=g_{ij}(\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^k}dy^k)\otimes(\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^h}dy^h)=g_{ij}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^k}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^h}dy^k\otimes dy^h$$
2. let $\tilde g_{kh}=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^k}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^h}$ I have tried to prove that it is equal to $\tilde g_{hk}$ in this way:
   I need $$\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^k}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^h}=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^h}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^k}$$
   I have done the following:
   $$\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^h}=\color{red}{\frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^i}}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^k}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^h}=\color{red}{\frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^i}}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^h}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^k}\iff \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^h}=\delta^k_h \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^k}=\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^h}$$
   but in the second equalities I am supposing what really I have to prove...so I am not convinced of what I have done

Please can you help me in solving these two questions?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Nope I want to prove that $\tilde g_{kh}=\tilde g_{hk}$, I have tried in the way above...but I think it is not right...

Comment: Ah ok so you want to prove that its symmetric. Use that $g_{ij}$ is symmetric so $\tilde{g}_{kh} \equiv g_{ij}\frac{dx^i}{dy^k}\frac{dx^j}{dy^h} = g_{ji}\frac{dx^i}{dy^k}\frac{dx^j}{dy^h}$. Now interchange the dummy summation indices $i$ and $j$ and you are left with the definition of $\tilde{g}_{hk}$

Comment: Sorry but $\tilde g_{kh}=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^k}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^h}$ without the $g_{ij}$...

Comment: But that makes no sense as an expression. Your right hand side depends on $i$ and $j$ while the left hand side does not.

Comment: Ah ok sorry! The last passage that you suggests consist in taking $j$ instead of $i$ and viceversa?

Comment: Yes. That is just a way to see it very explicitly (with exactly the same symbols for the summation labels as in the definition).

Comment: Ok thanks very much for all explanations and for the patience!